# How to enable Map Tip display text in qgis and qgiscloud?

Tags: qgis, layers, display, qgis-cloud

I'm using the free version of qgiscloud and qgis 2.4. I noticed that if I'll use the HTML option in "Map Tip display text", the map in qgiscloud will only show the title of the layer when I hover/click but it's working if I used the Field option. I would like to use the HTML option since I want to display/style multiple values based from an expression from different attributes of my layer, instead of using the Field option which will only display the selected field.